# Submit form php adding radio buttons

Tags: php, form-submit

Good morning,
I have a submit form,s code and it works perfectly. But when i add more inputs or radio buttons it stops working. I'm a front-end developer and i'm not very good at back-end development. Can anybody please help me to sort it out.
Thanks

```html
<html>
<head></head>

<body>
<form action="invia.php" method="POST">
Nome: <input type="text" name="nome">
<br><br>
Email: <input type="email" name="email"> 
<br><br>
Messaggio:
<br>
<textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="50" ></textarea>
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Invia">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

```html
<?php

$client = $_POST['nome'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

mail("someone@gmail.com","Contact from the site",$message,"From: $email\r\n");
?>
```

Comment: *"But when i add more inputs or radio buttons it stops working"* - you'll need to show us how you did that, because I for one, have no idea why.

Comment: Yes, i add a new input like this one Spedizione: <input type="text" name="spedizione"> and in php file i do the same as i have done for others. First i made a variable then i have put it after message variable. you can try it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give more details? I'm having problems understanding your issue (because not enough information).

Answer (score 0):

If we say we have this:

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male<br>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
```

Then only the last value will be taken because names overlap each other.